# Count the Total Minutes per interval based on raw data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Im trying to develop a template that will count the "on queue minutes" of the raw data.

The format would be like this. Ive tried some formula like count if, but it does not count the minutes itself but it count the occurrence per interval.

I need to get the minutes that will fall within the column M.

Let say 00:00-00:30 how many minutes is within the duration that fall within column J and K.

Cell N17 should have 30 because Cell J14:k14 fall within its range

[image: Count Per Interval]

Update,

I manage to include the formula listed Below, but I'm getting an error if in case the the duration is less than 15 minutes, or only 1 minute. Please see screenshot below: [image: image2]

Comment: Sooo.... what's the question? What are you trying to count exactly? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53121026/edit) to let us know what the expected outcome is and what exactly you are trying to do. Showing what it is you've tried (even if it doesn't work) can also be useful

Comment: You're probably looking for `SUMIF`, not `COUNTIF`. The latter only counts the number of times the conditions are met. The former will sum the values in the cells that match.

Comment: (There's also `SUMIFS()`/`COUNTIFS()` if those help)

Comment: Question have been revised

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I've had to add some helper columns to your data.

N.B. This will not work over multiple days.

First of all I rounded your times to the nearest minute with the following:

```
=MROUND(J14,1/60/24)
```

[image: Rounded Values]

Then I used this formula to 'bucket' your times accordingly into the helper columns for each row

```
=(IF(AND($M14>=MIN(P$12:P$13),$M14<=MAX(P$12:P$13)),(MAX(P$12:P$13)-$M14),0)+IF(AND($N14>=MIN(P$12:P$13),$N14<=MAX(P$12:P$13)),($N14-MIN(P$12:P$13)),0)+IF(AND($M14<MIN(P$12:P$13),$N14>MAX(P$12:P$13)),(P$13-P$12),0))*1440
```

[image]

Giving me the following results

[image]

I then summed each of these columns into my report view and hid all of the helper columns finally giving me:

[image]

You can change the intervals to whatever you want. I've done them at half hour intervals.

Comment: Hi Thank  you for providing the solution, I manage to adopt the formula and us it on our internal file, But it seems that we're getting an error if it start 1 minute after the interval

if you Key in 03:01 as Time Value Start and 03:15 as Time Value End, It will show 43.5666 which is not possible, 

Also if it is less than a minute, let say 03:07 as time values start and 03:08 as Time Value End it will show 30.78 as answer.